# Why can't .exes see files in /tmp in Windows Subsystem for Linux when the current working directory is a subdirectory of /mnt/c?

Tags: exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmp

When I run a .exe file from within WSL when the current working directory is `/mnt/c` or a subdirectory thereof, it seems to be unable to see files in `/tmp`. For example, `cd /mnt/c; notepad.exe $(mktemp)` throws "The system cannot find the file specified", even though non-exe executables work fine, such as `cat $(mktemp)`. Note that `mktemp` itself works fine, giving the correct output and actually creating the file.

Interestingly, I've noticed that this does not happen when the current working directory is `/`, among others. There, `notepad.exe $(mktemp)` works fine. However, when the current working directory is `/mnt/c` or a subdirectory of it, this strange behavior occurs.

Why can exes in WSL see `/tmp` when the current working directory is outside `/mnt/c`, but not from inside it? What causes this to happen?

If it matters, I'm on WSL1 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The output of `ps awx` with `notepad.exe $(mktemp)` running is

```
    1 ?        Ssl    0:58 /init
    5 tty1     Ss     0:00 /init
    6 tty1     S      0:09 -bash
 3227 tty1     S      0:00 /init /mnt/c/Windows/system32/notepad.exe /tmp/tmp.KQwVgByK8u
 3228 tty2     Ss     0:00 /init
 3229 tty2     S      0:00 -bash
 3255 tty2     R      0:00 ps awx
```

Process 3227's mount info is

````
=== /proc/3227/mountinfo ===
2 2 0:2 / / rw,noatime - lxfs rootfs rw
3 2 0:3 / /dev rw,noatime - tmpfs none rw,mode=755
4 2 0:4 / /sys rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime - sysfs sysfs rw
5 2 0:5 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime - proc proc rw
6 3 0:6 / /dev/pts rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime - devpts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620
7 2 0:7 / /run rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime - tmpfs none rw,mode=755
8 7 0:8 / /run/lock rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime - tmpfs none rw
9 7 0:9 / /run/shm rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime - tmpfs none rw
10 7 0:10 / /run/user rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime - tmpfs none rw,mode=755
11 5 0:11 / /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc rw,relatime - binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw
12 4 0:12 / /sys/fs/cgroup rw,relatime - tmpfs cgroup rw,mode=755
13 12 0:13 / /sys/fs/cgroup/devices rw,relatime - cgroup cgroup rw,devices
14 2 0:14 / /mnt/c rw,noatime - drvfs C:\134 rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off```
````

Comment: If I execute `notepad.exe $(mktemp)` from my home directory in WSL, it executes just fine. This is WSL 2 though, might be a difference in how these things are handled.

Comment: Try it in `/mnt/c`. Does it still work?

Comment: Looking at this from the Linux perspective this behavior does remind me a lot about a filesystem namespacing issues. I have no deeper insight in how WSL works, but I'd not be surprised if WSL made some heave use of the Linux namespace APIs (used for things like containers and such) to overlay or bind `/mnt/c` and when you're process starts from there it sees a *different* `/tmp`

Comment: Also keep in mind that `notepad.exe`, which is a windows executable will probably somehow be "lifted" into the host windows environment and the Linux filesystem be exported to the windows environment. **For the sake of debugging, can you start `notepad.exe $(mktemp)` and with it running list all processes with `ps awx`. And if possible show us the output of `for M in /proc/*/mountinfo ; do echo "===" $M "===" ; cat $M ; echo ; done`?**

Comment: @datenwolf done

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same problem just now. Found the solution to this on superuser:
https://superuser.com/a/1728907/144431

You need to update wsl utilities to the latest (apparently this years-old bug was finally fixed). On Ubuntu, it's just a matter of doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wslutilities/wslu
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```